# Azure Function's hard dependency on Newtonsoft 11.0.2 and Docker containers

Tags: c#, azure, nuget, azure-functions

I wanted to create an application running on Azure Function. Problem is that Azure Functions SDK has a deendency on Newtonsoft "=11.0.2". Unfortunately one of 3rd party dependencies of my project requires Newtonsoft ">=12.*".
That creates a conflict and my application just crashes at the point where 3rd party dependency tries to access some API of Newtonsoft that does not exist in version 11.0.2.

I though that a solution would be to deploy the function as container. However, looking at [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image) I see that Docker images use Functions SDK anyway, so problem would be the same.

Is there some option to run Azure Functions app without using Azure Functions SDK? I was thinking that Docker deployment would allow me to run anything on Azure Functions, maybe even using programming language that is not supported by default by Azure Functions.

Or, maybe, I could solve my problem in some other way?

Comment: This is still an issue. I don't see any solution here https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4049

Comment: @HariHaran I'm aware of this. That's why I thought about Docker - form my understanding, it would just allow me to run anything inside container. Especially looking at the fact that my app runs on interval (every 5 minutes), without any requests, my docker app does not need to even accept any input - it just runs.

Answer (score 1):

There was [recently a change](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/pull/331) to relax the requirement to ">= 11.0.2" in Functions v2. The change is not yet in GA, but you can get the prerelease verions by referencing `Install-Package Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions -Version 1.0.30-beta1`.

Functions without the Functions SDK is a Webjob. You may have noticed that the Webjobs SDK is a dependency of the Functions SDK. You can certainly go this route, but you loose quite a bit of the Functions functionality. The biggest loses would be the consumption billing and the prebuilt service connections. Triggers work in a similar fashion, but you need to write the code to connect to the service.

Comment: I wish it was ">=12.0.2" :)

Comment: One step at a time. :) I reached out to the product team and they are looking to have 1.0.30 in GA by the end of the month.